# How insert element into json object using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, yii2

I am Creating **javascript variable** From **PHP associative array** as Below :

```
var frontdata= '<?php echo json_encode(Yii::$app->mycomponent->getFrontActorID());?>';
frontdata=$.parseJSON(frontdata);
```

It gives me Following output :

> Object {1: "User", 9: "Driver", 10: "Waiter", 11: "WareHouse Keeper"}

Now I want to add one more record in object.

i.e. 12:"Admin"

So,it looks Like

> Object {1: "User", 9: "Driver", 10: "Waiter", 11: "WareHouse
>   Keeper",12:"Admin"}

How to Do this using javascript or jQuery ?

I already Tried `JSON.stringify` and `frontdata.items.append`,but it is not working. or i don't know how to implement it.

Thanks

Comment: `frontdata[12] = 'Admin';`

Comment: try $("#formId").serialize()+"&Admin="+'12';

Comment: @JaromandaX ,it is working , post your comment as answer so i can accept

Comment: It's javascript, not some script of java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JSON** Data in Javascript behave like Normal Javascript Objects or rather **is** (in essence) **an Object**. You could treat the JSON Data like You would any Normal JS Object and Here is how:

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var frontdata = {1: "User", 9: "Driver", 10: "Waiter", 11: "WareHouse Keeper"};

    // ADD THE NEW ENTRY(IES) TO THE JSON OBJECT:
    frontdata[12] = "Admin";
    frontdata[24] = "Chef";


    console.log(frontdata);
    // YIELDS:: 
    Object {
              1: "User", 
              9: "Driver", 
              10: "Waiter", 
              11: "WareHouse Keeper", 
              12: "Admin", 
              24: "Chef"
            }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks,but it gives me output as :[["1","User"],["9","Driver"],["10","Waiter"],["11","WareHouse Keeper"],[12,"Admin"]].

Comment: frontdata[12] = 'Admin'; is working as Jaromanda suggested in comment

Comment: @YasinPatel     Check the Updated version which should work just fine.... cheers and good luck...

Comment: @PrateekRathore  You are quite Correct, however ***The DataType of the Key is not really of Primary Importance here...*** The important thing is to append extra Data to the JSON Object.... ;-)